# mat-grid-list and mat-grid-tile not aligned as needed

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui

Here is my stackblitz link : [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dashboard-inchara-approach-2-stackoverflow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I have take a mat-grid-list that spans 3 columns. Under group-1, spline occupies 2 columns, pie occupies 1 column and has to be adjacent to each other. However, the output is not the case.

How do I fix this?

```
Required output :

Group-1

spline works!   pie works!

bar works!

Group-2

route works!     marker works!   status works!

Group-3

trail works!    striped works!   nonstriped works!

Group-4

switch works!    indicator works!    formatted works!

nonformatted works!   line works!

Group-5

bar works!
```